# How to remove old assembly artifacts in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Assembly retention policies are standard, but artifacts are not removed. Why they are not deleted and how to remove them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How to remove old assembly artifacts in Azure Pipelines?

It depends on the retention policy settings of your build pipeline and whether you manually select retention.

You could select one of those build pipeline to check the reatenion leases:

[image]

You can modify the related retention policy settings.

Or you could remove reatenion leases and then delete the pipeline for those old assembly artifacts pipelines.

Then those old assembly artifacts will not display in the release pipeline.